# Iteratively predict a sequence with GRU(Keras)

Tags: keras, lstm

I'm learning how to generate a sequence with LSTM/GRU. 
The network summary is:

Embedding (None, 135, 128) -->
   3* GRU (None, 135, 128) -->
   TimeDist (None, 135, 89)

My idea is that first input=[1, 0, 0, ..., 0], then assume the predict output model.predict(input)= 2, then I add the 2 to the next position as a new input, [1, 2, 0, ...0]. iteratively for 135 times.

Is that a right approach or not? I'm a little confused. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can look at the [seq-to-seq tutorial from Keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html). This is not exactly what you intended but you may get some ideas from that.

Comment: Thank you, I saw this before and I thought they used the same way as I posted above, not very sure.